# Spring MVC: How to get the right URL for controllers?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm a newbie to web development as well as Spring MVC. I'm testing on a silly example for the controllers, however, it seems that the controller has never been called, or at least it doesn't work as expected.

The goal is to click on a hyperlink in the "test.jsp" page and direct to "customers.jsp" page, with the controller being called, so that a message will be passed to the "customers.jsp" page.

Now I have the "customers.jsp" page showing correctly but with no transferred message displayed. The URL is `http://localhost:8080/WebProject/view/customers.jsp`.

Could you please help me find out the problem? I suppose it's because of the URL mapped to the controller. But is there a way that I can check the right URL to map for controllers? Thanks!

*** updates at the end ***

The project structure is like this:

`--webapp
   |--view
       |--*.jsp
   |--WEB-INF
       |--*.xml`

Here is my code:

test.jsp

```
<a href='<c:url value="customers.jsp"/>'>show customers</a>
```

or

```
<a href="customers.jsp">show customers</a>
```

both works properly.

customers.jsp

```
<h2>return: ${list}</h2>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customers") 
public class MenuController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listCustomers() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("customers");
        model.addObject("list", "controller: a list of customers");
        return model;
    }
}
```

and the configuration:

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

myDispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.spring.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.spring.model" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/view/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

UPDATE for those who might see this post later :

There is indeed a problem of url mapping as indicated by @javafan and @Beri. But after changing the url to `<a href="customers">show customers</a>` I still got Error 404 at `http://localhost:8080/WebProject/customers`. This is in fact caused by a package scanning error, so the Controllers cannot be found. To solve this, simply change the line in the "myDispatcher-servlet.xml" file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.spring.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.spring.model" />
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="model" />
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javatan is right:
Try

```
<protocol>/<host>:<port>/WebProject/customers
```

Inside InternalResourceViewResolver bean definition you define prefix and suffix, those values are used to find jsp files in yur application. And have nothing in common with urls that your application has created.

Your url paths are defined inside controllers( not inside InternalResourceViewResolver).
So after application name you are using paths defined inside controllers.

You can also define @RequestMapping("/customers") on a method:)

Check if you have in your bean definition line, that looks like this:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.web.controllers"/>
```

This definition will scan for all classes inside com.project.web.controllers package (and subpackages) to find classes marked with @Controller annotation. You can check for more here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html, chapters:

- 17.3.1 - how to register a controller
- 17.2 -how web.xml looks like

I hope this will help.
Ok, I have run local example with JSP:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value> <!-- Here you have your spring bean definition -->
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MenuController {

    @RequestMapping( value="/customers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listCustomers() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("customers");
        model.addObject("list", "controller: a list of customers");
        return model;
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.programcreek.helloworld.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The explanation is indeed useful. But when I change the href to "customers", I got 404 error at url 'WebProject/customers'. Any suggestion?

Comment: First i web.xml change <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>. So that all paths will be mapped, not only /.

Comment: Secondly do you have in your code definition like this: <context:component-scan base-package="my.app.controllers"/>. Here lets assume your controllers lie in package my.app.controllers. That line will scan all classes in this package in search for controllers.

Comment: I do have component-scan configured in the xml. And when I change web.xml to <url-pattern>/*<url-pattern>, all pages are renderred as plain text in the browser..do you have an idea?

Comment: Can you make a breakpoint in our controller? first of all you need to check if you get inside your controller on request. Blank page is a good sign, its better than 404:)

Comment: I hope this can help you: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm
This is the simplest example on web:)

Comment: the 404 wasn't gone, it's the test.jsp page becoming plain text... :( btw, I'm using SpringMVC 4.0.6 and Tomcat v7.0

Comment: If you want, I could send you my working sandbox, I also used Tomcat 7, and Spring 4, with Maven to build project and dependencies.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It was in fact caused by a stupid error in <context:component-scan>. I made an update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get the url of the server:

```
 "<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customers.jsp">show customers</a>"
```

And you are mapping the Controller to /customers

so the url should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/WebProject/customers/customers.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly calling customer.jsp. Instead you have to call controller which in turn pass the request to customer.jsp. in HREF attribute, you need to mention value which is given in @RequestMapping annotation in your controller.

For more detailed example, visit my blog [Here](http://morejava4u.blogspot.com/2013/12/html-components-in-spring-mvc.html)

Comment: Your blog is very helpful. but I when I change the href to "customer", which is the value given in @RequestMapping, I get error 404 on the page `/WebProject/customers`. It seems that the controller is never called. Do you have any idea?